# StatHG is non-existent

Tags: mercurial, metrics

In the CVS/SVN world, there are various statistics/metrics tools. E.G., [StatCVS](http://statcvs.sourceforge.net/), [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). There are others I've seen.

However, I've not seen similar statistics and visualizations for Mercurial(aka hg).

(1) Are there any out there?

(2) If so, what are they?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as an initial tool, there's the churn extension that get's you some basic statistics about repository. For details on how to activate and use it see [ChurnExtension](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/ChurnExtension) on the mercurial wiki.

If you are interested in a specific (group of) changesets and what files the change, then diffstat is also a good help.

Comment: I've looked at churn, and it doesn't seem very usable for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

We just made the project [StatHG](https://bitbucket.org/fundacion_jala/stathg) publicly available. The project had the goal to develop a tool to extract statistical information from a Mercurial repository and build reports about the work done within a group of developers in a similar spirit as StatCVS. Please take a look and see if it fits your needs. If it doesn’t let us know so we can list the requirements on the TODO list. Thanks for any feedback we can get!

Comment: Pablo, this looks fascinating. Unfortunately, er, you don't have a download link on bitbucket, or a makefile... How do you build this?

Comment: Paul, we've added a zip file with the binaries and instructions on how to run the application. The only prerequisite is that you have at least jre 1.6 installed on your machine.

Comment: This looks nifty! I was able to generate a html report on OpenJDK version: `java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but your best bet is to ask on the [Mercurial mailing list](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/MailingLists).

Hg is still relatively new so it's "behind" SVN when it comes to tools.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed version control systems such as Mercurial are often used in a way that produces a complex history with lots of merges. That makes some of the plots that StatCVS produces such as lines of code against time harder to read.

Comment: Yeah, it's not as "clean" as the CVS model. Still though, I'd like to be able to do some nice stats such as a detailed churn readout.

Comment: @dickon: it's still possible to gather useful stats from dvcs. see gitstat: http://mirror.celinuxforum.org/gitstat/